# Discord.js - How to send message when a user joins a role?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have this for when someone joins the server:

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => {
    console.log(`${member.user.username} joined the server`)
    const embedJoins = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor(colourColl)
    .setDescription(`**${member.user.username}** just joined the server`)
    client.channels.cache.get(channelMissionControl).send(embedJoins);
});
```

I want to do something similar for when a user joins a specific role.
**Can this be done?**

Answer (score 0):

#### Client#guildMemberUpdate

`guildMemberUpdate` is a client event designed to provide a callback whenever there was an update to a member of the guild - Such as nickname changes, and most importantly **role updates**.
We can easily use this event to determine when a user's role has been updated, and callback an embed to be sent to a certain channel we'd be looking for.

Keep in mind, before this is done, you'd be looking to check what action the member has taken - As if he were to update his nickname and not the role, we'd get a bunch of errors. Luckily, `guildMemberUpdate` provides us with 2 parameters: `oldMember` and `newMember`, which are both GuildMember objects we can use to find if there has been any activity with the member's roles. Let's set 2 variables:

```
const oldRoles = oldMember.roles.cache;
const newRoles = newMember.roles.cache;
```

From there, we can determine whether a roles list has been updated for a member:

```
if (oldRoles.size < newRoles.size) {
  // code
}
```

#### Code Example

```
client.on('guildMemberUpdate', oldMember, newMember => {
  const oldRoles = oldMember.roles.cache;
  const newRoles = newMember.roles.cache;
  if (oldRoles.size < newRoles.size) {
    const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
    .setTitle('Roles updated!');
    .setDescription(`${newMember.user.username}'s roles have been updated!`);
    .setColor(3426654);
    newMember.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name.toLowerCase() === 'logs').send(Embed);
  }
})
```

You can read more about `guildMemberUpdate` here: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberUpdate

Comment: Thanks! This seems to send a message when the user joins any role.
How would this work for joining a specific role?

Comment: I believe for that purpose you'd be looking at the idea of fetching audit logs - You could look at the roles updated and determine what role has been given, then check if it matches the role object's name you're looking for!

Comment: Actually, I've just found an easier solution to this. Check this out: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/faq.html#how-do-i-check-which-role-was-added-removed-and-for-which-member

Also, if my answer helped you, please mark it as correct :3

Comment: Brilliant!
Its so close, but the log shows this:
The roles Corp Visitor,@everyone were added to Mr M - Tester
It's including @everyone

Comment: We could add another check for the filter to determine whether the freshly added role was the everyone role using the `everyone` role method: `role.id !== newMember.guild.roles.everyone.id`